# Matching only first occurrence in C# regex

Tags: c#, regex

I want to match only first `Hash=""` in this.

```
Hash="123"Hash="AEBB1247209BC9E10EA2054F1813DFD7BB9EEF23FEF7C867FCFCEC69CA0C2A6D"Hash="1"
```

I tried with regex `(Hash="[0-9,A-F]+")?`

But it always matches all 3 `Hash=""`. Is there any way to fix this? I am using C# Regex library.

Comment: Use a caret `^` in your regex to specify the start of the string: `^(Hash="[0-9,A-F]+")`

Comment: The first Hash could be at the middle of a string.

Comment: `string result = Regex.Match(source, @"Hash=""[0-9A-F]+"").Value;` in order to get the first match. Or if you want just a number, `string result = Regex.Match(source, @"Hash=""(?<hash>[0-9A-F]+)"").Groups["hash"].Value;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [Match()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.match?view=netframework-4.8), not [Matches()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: Is there any equivalent method for `Regex.Replace()`

Comment: Regex.Replace() can do it, just use its form with 3 arguments: `Replace(String, String, Int32)`, the third argument determines the number of times the replacement should occur. Use 1 to replace just the first occurence.

Comment: I have the same question however isn't the third argument the actual string being inserted into the pattern match? `.Replace(String, Pattern, ReplacementString)` where would the count be in this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer would be to use `regex.match()` instead of `regex.matches()`.

The first one returns the first match only, the second one returns all matches.

However, there is a regexp that does the job and returns only the first one, whatever you call match() or matches() :

`(?<!Hash="[0-9A-F]+".*)Hash="[0-9A-F]+"`

*Note : this works in C#, but won't work in most other languages (like Java)*

`(?<!Hash="[0-9A-F]+".*)` is a negative lookahead : it should not be possible to match `Hash="[0-9A-F]+".*` on the left side of current position (the part already read). In other words, it only matches the first Hash.

Two things regarding your current regex : `(Hash="[0-9,A-F]+")?`

1. The `,` between 0-9 and A-F is not a separator between the 2 ranges. It just adds `,` in the valid character set, which is probably not you goal (you'll accept hashes like `0123,456`)
2. The final `?` indicates that the whole group is optional. So, if it cannot be matched, it's still a success. As a consequence, strings like `abcd` will match (and `matches()` will return 5 matches of length 0: before a, between a and b, between b and c, etc...)

Comment: Is there any similar method for `Regex.Replace()`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below regex to achieve your functionality:

```
(Hash="([0-9,A-F]+)[^"]*).*"
```

Explanation:

- 1st Capturing Group `(Hash="([0-9,A-F]+)[^"]*)`
  Hash=" matches the characters Hash=" literally (case sensitive)
- 2nd Capturing Group ([0-9,A-F]+):
- Match a single character present in the list below `[0-9,A-F]+`
  `+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
- `0-9` a single character in the range between 0 (index 48) and 9 (index 57) (case sensitive)
- `,` matches the character , literally (case sensitive)
- `A-F` a single character in the range between A (index 65) and F (index 70) (case sensitive)
- Match a single character not present in the list below `[^"]*`
- `*` Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
- `"` matches the character " literally (case sensitive)
- `.*` matches any character (except for line terminators)
- `*` Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
- `"` matches the character " literally (case sensitive)

Working example: https://regex101.com/r/XTqhyU/2

Comment: This matches all 3 Hashs

Comment: @FaisalM Your first Hash match is in group 2 for the strings in the above posted example